# Ionicmodal Doesn't Open Until Third Click/Tap

Tags: ionic-framework

I have set the `on-tap` value of a `div` to open a modal which is defined in the page's controller. The `div` is part of an `ng-repeat` section. The modal function also accepts some variables passed to it by the `div`.

When the app is first started on my device (iPhone 6 running iOS 7), I have to tap the div three times before the modal will open. After that, it opens consistently when I tap. But when the app first starts, I have to tap the div 3 times.

There are no errors at all in the console. Once the modal does open, it works as expected.

Any advice?

Here's the code:

HTML

```
  <div on-tap="doModal('{{embed.ID}}','reply','{{embed.oembed}}','{{embed.user}}');">
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 75 72" width="100" height="50">
      <path d="imagestuffhere"/>
      </svg>
   </div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.doModal = function(this_ID,modaltype,this_oembed,this_user) {    
  $scope.contact = {
    name:   this_ID,
    info:   modaltype,
    oembed: this_oembed,
    user:   this_user
  }

  if (modaltype == 'repost') {
    $scope.modaltempl = 'templates/repost-modal.html';
  }
  else if (modaltype == 'reply') {
    $scope.modaltempl = 'templates/reply-modal.html';
  }
  else if (modaltype == 'like') {
    $scope.modaltempl = 'templates/like-modal.html';
  }
  else {
    $scope.modaltempl = 'templates/like-modal.html';
  }

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl($scope.modaltempl, {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    $scope.modal.show();
    console.log($scope.modaltempl);
  });
};    

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
```

I've tried pulling the `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl($scope.modaltempl,` bit outside of `$scope.doModal` and calling `$scope.modal.show` from within `$scope.doModal`, but the result is the same.

It definitely gets to the `scope.modal.show();` statement even when the modal does not open, because the `console.log` I've included just after it gets output.

Before I had added the svg to the interface, I was testing this using a `button` element and had the same issue. It also had the same issue when I used `ng-click` instead of `on-tap`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was not in the Ionic controller code nor the triggering html, but in the modal template, itself.

Per the Ionic documentation, I had each of my modal templates wrapped in this:

`<script type="text/ng-template" id="repost-modal.html"></script>`

By removing that and replacing it with just `<ion-modal-view></ion-modal-view>` the issue was resolved and the modals now open very nicely on the first click.